# Nuxt Image module not rendering dynamic images (Nuxt 2)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using the Nuxt Image module for a Nuxt 2 project and my dynamic images that are props passed to the component are not rendering. If I use  tags they work as expected.  tags also work outside of components that are not dynamic.

Does not work:

```
 <nuxt-img
        :class="
          imageIsLeft
            ? 'md:-translate-x-5 xl:-translate-x-0'
            : 'md:translate-x-5 xl:translate-x-0'
        "
        class="image-full md:max-w-[500px] md:w-full"
        :src="require(`@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg`)"
        height="569"
        width="500"
        loading="lazy"
        alt="headshot"
      />
```

Works:

```
 <img
        :class="
          imageIsLeft
            ? 'md:-translate-x-5 xl:-translate-x-0'
            : 'md:translate-x-5 xl:translate-x-0'
        "
        class="image-full md:max-w-[500px] md:w-full"
        :src="require(`@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg`)"
        height="569"
        width="500"
        loading="lazy"
        alt="headshot"
      />

 



  Page level (works):

  <nuxt-img
            quality="60"
            alt="envelope"
            width="39"
            height="33"
            class="w-[25px] xs:w-[39px]"
            src="/img/icons/envelope.svg"
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the nuxt-img add a

```
:src="require(`@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg`)"
```

to

```
:img-src="require(`@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg`)"
```

the code:

```
<nuxt-picture
      :class="
        imageIsLeft
          ? 'md:-translate-x-5 xl:-translate-x-0'
          : 'md:translate-x-5 xl:translate-x-0'
      "
      class="image-full md:max-w-[500px] md:w-full"
      :img-src="require(`@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg`)"
      height="569"
      width="500"
      loading="lazy"
      alt="headshot"
    >
    <template #default="{ src, sources, imgAttrs }">
    <img :src="src" :srcset="sources" :width="500" :height="569" :alt="headshot" :loading="'lazy'" :class="imgAttrs.class" />
  </template>
</nuxt-picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `require("@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg")` would not work.

The following is from the `@nuxtJS/image` [documentation](https://image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img):

> src should be in the form of an absolute path for static images in `static/` directory. Otherwise path that is expected by provider that starts with / or a URL.

> Images should be stored in the static/ directory of your project.
> For example, when using `<nuxt-img src="/nuxt-icon.png" />`, it should be placed in `static/` folder under the path `static/nuxt-icon.png`.

So instead of using:

```
<nuxt-img :src="require(`@/static/img/main/${image}.jpg`)"/>
```

Using this should solve the problem:

```
<nuxt-img :src="`/img/main/${image}.jpg`"/>
```